# How to import data from an xml file into cassandra directly

Tags: java, xml, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-jdbc

I am trying to insert a data from an xml file into Cassandra database directly. It has 1089090 records on it.

I tried to read it pragmatically using java and got this exception after about 77000 records.

> java.sql.SqlNontrasientConnectionException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTTransportException

Comment: can u tell me command to export data from mxl file to cassandra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your connection is got broken after processing some data. I faced such issue once & solved that by using connection pooling. Can you tell me how you are getting the connection in your java code ?

Comment: i wasn't using connection pooling before and connection pooling did the job for me.